# Email notification on field value change?

Tags: plugin-development, field, emails

Currently, I have the need to get an email notification, only when a particular field(s) have changed value. In my use case, a few light switches. Is there currently any way to get notified of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprout Email allows you to create [Custom Events](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/docs/notifications/custom-events) where you could add a new rule that allows a user to set the options needed to meet your use case.

Additionally, the entire EntryModel will be handed off to the Notification when your Custom Event fires, so you could have logic in your notification template that sends customized messages depending on the different conditions that were met, just like in any other Twig template.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write a plugin to do that.  Thankfully, it's not too difficult:

https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction